# Maximum Rotation Speed

Tags: rotation, speed

I looked at a question, elsewhere on this site, relating to the maximum 'theoretical' speed of rotation. The explanation using the speed on a black hole event horizon seemed reasonable to this person.

However  – being wholly ignorant in this topic a well as many others – I then wondered about two 'lightspeed limited event horizon' spinning black holes approaching each other. Assuming they are rotating in the same direction (parallel to each other) then the *apparent relative* speed of the adjacent spinning event horizons, as they approach contact, could be considered as having 'double' the speed? Surely this make no sense?

Presumably space-time steps in to make it all work out, and that's when it all goes **bang** – to keep the laws of physics intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about the metric of two black hole spinning at the speed of light in opposite directions and approaching may make someone's head hurt.

Fortunately there is no need of such complicated concepts to solve your paradox, just special relativity.

Imagine you are on a rocket, going almost at the speed of light, and you see another rocket, also going almost at the speed of light, but in the opposite direction. When it sweeps next to you, do you see it going at double the speed of light?

Of course not, velocities don't simply *add* in special relativity. The law of composition of velocities is

$$u' = \frac{u+v}{1+\frac{uv}{c^2}}$$

Where $v$ is your speed, $u$ is the speed of the rocket and $u'$ is the speed of the rocked as seen by you. Let's say that $u=v=0.9c$, then

$$u'= {2c\cdot 0.9 \over 1+ 0.9^2} \approx 0.994c < c$$

In the case of the two black holes there are a lot of other effects that could slightly change the numbers, but the core concept is the same. Two objects going at the speed of light in opposite directions don't see each other going faster than the speed of light

Comment: I understand what you are saying, though I would be lying if I said I understood the detail - my experience with mathematics is limited and aged. In any case, thank you for taking the time to explain it. I am a little wiser.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact you don't have to get to a black hole to make sense of this.

Consider a light source and two diametrically opposite light beams emanating out of it. Each beam travels at the speed to light (assume vacuum for simplicity). Hence clearly, the *relative velocity* is $2c$.

Never the less, we know that this can happens. So, it does make sense for relative speed to be greater than speed of light.

---

Strictly speaking, when you "add" two velocities close to the speed of light the result will never exceed the speed of light. Clearly this is no usual addition of vectors, but rather a special kind of addition which respects the [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity#Lorentz_transformation_of_velocities).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the trouble to explain that to me. Clearly, intuition can get one into all sorts of muddles in this field.